# Convertir columnas en filas con PIVOT

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 'Impartidas', DAY(kh.Hora) AS 'Dia'
FROM K_Horario kh
WHERE CONVERT (char(10),kh.Hora,20) BETWEEN '2017-07-03' AND '2017-07-09'
GROUP BY DAY(kh.Hora) ORDER BY DAY(kh.Hora)
```

Y me devuelve los siguiente resultado:

> ```
> +------------+-----+
> | Impartidas | Dia |
> +------------+-----+
> |         31 |   3 |
> |         28 |   4 |
> |         29 |   5 |
> |         27 |   6 |
> |         24 |   7 |
> |          7 |   8 |
> |          7 |   9 |
> +------------+-----+
> ```

Mi objetivo es que los días los mande en forma de fila por lo cual hago lo siguiente:

```
SELECT 'ClasesPorDia' AS Dia, [3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9]
FROM (SELECT DAY(kh.Hora)FROM K_Horario kh WHERE CONVERT(char(10),kh.Hora,20) BETWEEN '2017-07-03' AND '2017-07-09')
PIVOT (COUNT(*) FOR DAY(kh.Hora) IN ([3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9]))
```

Comment: La tabla k_horario tiene alguna llave primaria?, como se llama ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes una llave primaria en tu tabla K_Horario, esta consulta te servirá, reemplaza LlavePrimaria en los dos sitios que la puse con tu propia llave primaria :

```
SELECT 'ClasesPorDia' AS Dia, [3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9]
FROM (SELECT LlavePrimaria, DAY(kh.Hora) as DiaClase FROM K_Horario kh WHERE 
CONVERT(char(10),kh.Hora,20) BETWEEN '2017-07-03' AND '2017-07-09') as TablaDias
PIVOT (COUNT(LlavePrimaria) FOR DiaClase IN ([3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9])) as PivotDias
```

Saludos,

Comment: SELECT 'ClasesPorDia' AS Dia, [3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9]
FROM (SELECT OIDHorario, DAY(Hora) as DiaClase FROM K_Horario WHERE 
CONVERT(char(10),Hora,20) BETWEEN '2017-07-03' AND '2017-07-09')
PIVOT (COUNT(OIDHorario) FOR DiaClase IN ([3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9]))    Me sale el siguiente error: Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PIVOT'.

Comment: Intenta de nuevo con la actualizacion por favor.

Comment: Acabo de publicar la respuesta que encontre, muchas gracias. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta la encontre agregando un alias después del SELECT y otro después del PIVOT, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
    SELECT 'ClasesPorDia' AS Dia, [3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9]
FROM (SELECT OIDHorario, DAY(Hora) as DiaClase FROM K_Horario WHERE 
CONVERT(char(10),Hora,20) BETWEEN '2017-07-03' AND '2017-07-09') AS V
PIVOT (COUNT(OIDHorario) FOR DiaClase IN ([3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9])) AS PTS
```