# Totalizar la suma en función pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

El día de ayer realizaba una pregunta [Convertir columnas en filas con PIVOT](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/95207/convertir-columnas-en-filas-con-pivot) en donde solicitaba ayuda con la función PIVOT la cual pude solucionar y agilizar un poco de la siguiente manera:

```
    WITH Clases2(Nombre, FechaClase, Total) AS
(SELECT ki.NomLargo, DAY(kh.Hora), COUNT(kh.Hora) FROM K_Horario kh
INNER JOIN K_Instructor ki ON kh.OIDEmpleado=ki.OIDEmpleado
WHERE CONVERT (char(10),Hora,20) BETWEEN '2017-07-03' AND '2017-07-09'
GROUP BY ki.NomLargo, DAY(kh.Hora))
SELECT * FROM Clases2
PIVOT (COUNT(Total) FOR FechaClase IN([3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9])) PVT
```

El resultado lo muestra de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero quisiera que se agregaran dos totales, un total por columna y el otro total por fila. Es decir: un total a lado del día 9 y el otro total abajo del último nombre. un ejemplo:

```
    Nombres             | 8 | 9 | totales
    GARCIA LOPEZ EFRAIN | 1 | 0 | 5
    totales             | 7 | 0 | 38
```

¿Pudieran ayudarme?

Comment: Puedes mostrar cuál sería el resultado que quieres obtener?

Comment: Un total por fila y uno por columna, es decir: A lado del día 9 colocar un total y abajo del ultimo nombre otro total.

Comment: agrega el comentario a la pregunta asi sera mas completa

Answer (score 1):

Para el total por fila, tendrías que simplemente usar la suma del resto de las columnas. Para el total por columna, te recomiendo que uses `GROUPING SETS`:

```
WITH Clases2(Nombre, FechaClase, Total) 
AS
(
    SELECT  ki.NomLargo, 
            DAY(kh.Hora), 
            COUNT(kh.Hora) 
    FROM K_Horario kh
    INNER JOIN K_Instructor ki 
        ON kh.OIDEmpleado=ki.OIDEmpleado
    WHERE CONVERT (char(10),Hora,20) BETWEEN '2017-07-03' AND '2017-07-09'
    GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((ki.NomLargo, DAY(kh.Hora)),())
)
SELECT  ISNULL(NomLargo,'Total') NomLargo, 
        [3],
        [4],
        [5],
        [6],
        [7],
        [8],
        [9],
        [3] + [4] + [5] + [6] + [7] + [8] + [9] Totales
FROM Clases2
PIVOT (COUNT(Total) FOR FechaClase IN([3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9])) PVT
ORDER BY CASE WHEN NomLargo IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, NomLargo;
```

Para SQL Server 2005 puedes usar `ROLLUP`:

```
WITH Clases2(Nombre, FechaClase, Total) 
AS
(
    SELECT  ki.NomLargo, 
            DAY(kh.Hora), 
            COUNT(kh.Hora) 
    FROM K_Horario kh
    INNER JOIN K_Instructor ki 
        ON kh.OIDEmpleado=ki.OIDEmpleado
    WHERE CONVERT (char(10),Hora,20) BETWEEN '2017-07-03' AND '2017-07-09'
    GROUP BY ROLLUP(ki.NomLargo, DAY(kh.Hora))
)
SELECT  ISNULL(NomLargo,'Total') NomLargo, 
        [3],
        [4],
        [5],
        [6],
        [7],
        [8],
        [9],
        [3] + [4] + [5] + [6] + [7] + [8] + [9] Totales
FROM Clases2
PIVOT (COUNT(Total) FOR FechaClase IN([3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9])) PVT
ORDER BY CASE WHEN NomLargo IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, NomLargo;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, lo ejecuto y me manda el sig error:                   Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Incorrect syntax near 'SETS'.

Comment: @GuillermoRicardoSpindolaBri ah, bueno, qué versión de SQL Server estás usando?

Comment: Me conecto a través de TOAD, pero el servidor ejecuta una instancia de SQL Server 2005.

Comment: @GuillermoRicardoSpindolaBri Entonces puedes tratar de usar `ROLLUP` como puse en la actualización de mi respuesta

Comment: tengo el mismo problema, pero la verdad no te entendi